# Where is the XAMPP control panel config file?

Tags: php, windows, apache, batch-file, xampp

I'm creating an installer batch file which automatically installs XAMPP and configures Apache. Altough, this installer should launch the Apache server automatically when the system starts up.

My idea is that the batch file should use `mklink` to put XAMPP into the Windows startup folder, since in XAMPP you can configure to start Apache automatically. The problem is that I have to configure it in a config file as the installer batch file can't access it in another way.

I searched for this config file in the whole xampp folder but couldn't find it. I also tried linking the `apache_start.bat` file directly inside the startup folder, but that just gave me an error.

Here's my whole german batch file:

```
@ECHO off
CHCP 65001
SETLOCAL
TITLE Montemanager - Automatische Installation
:INTRO
ECHO ###### Montemanager - Automatische Installation #####
ECHO # ------------------------------------------------- #
ECHO #   Vielen Dank, dass Sie sich für Montemanager     #
ECHO #  entschieden haben. Diese Anwendung wird nun eine #
ECHO #       automatische Installation durchführen.      #
ECHO #                  Das bedeutet:               #
ECHO # ------------------------------------------------- #
ECHO #    1. Es werden alle erforderlichen Komponente    #
ECHO #  auf diesem System installiert. ACHTUNG:     #
ECHO #  Dieses Programm darf nur auf dem Server     #
ECHO #  ausgeführt werden!                      #
ECHO #    2. Ihre Lizenz des Montemanager wird aktiviert #
ECHO #      und der zuständige Server gestartet.        #
ECHO # ------------------------------------------------- #
ECHO #      Mehr Information finden Sie auf:        #
ECHO #   www.montemanager.de/help?page=installer    #
ECHO #####################################################
PAUSE
:PROMPT
SET /P AREYOUSURE=Hiermit wird die automatische Installation ausgeführt. Dies kann einige Zeit in Anspruch nehmen. Es werden ca. 0 MB Speicherplatz sowie eine Internetverbindung benötigt. Möchten Sie fortfahren? (j/n) 
IF /I "%AREYOUSURE%" NEQ "j" GOTO ABORT
ECHO Dateien verschieben...
IF EXIST \montemanager RMDIR \montemanager /s /q
MOVE /y montemanager \montemanager
CD montemanager/setup/dependencies
GOTO DOWNLOAD
:DOWNLOAD
ECHO Herunterladen von XAMPP...
CURL -o xampp.exe https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/7.4.3/xampp-windows-x64-7.4.3-0-VC15-installer.exe --ssl-no-revoke --location
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO NETWORK_ERROR
ECHO Fertig. Bitte drücken Sie eine Taste, sobald die Anwendung installiert ist.
START xampp.exe
PAUSE
CD \xampp\php
PHP \montemanager\setup\apache_config\index.php
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO INTERNAL_ERROR
:STARTUP
CD \montemanager\setup\apache_config\
SET "admins="
SET "prev="
FOR /f "delims=" %%A IN ('net localgroup administrators') DO (
 CALL SET "admins=%%admins%% %%prev%%"
 SET "prev=%%A"
)
SET admins=%admins:*- =%
ECHO Nun müssen Sie Administratorrechte angeben.
PAUSE
RUNAS startup.bat /user %admins%
PAUSE
:END
ECHO Die Installation der Serverkomponente ist abgeschlossen.
PAUSE
CD \xampp
START apache_start.bat
START mysql_start.bat
START "" https://localhost/setup/manager.php
EXIT
:ABORT
ECHO Abgebrochen.
PAUSE
EXIT
:NETWORK_ERROR
ECHO Es ist ein Netzwerkfehler aufgetreten. Bitte überprüfen Sie Ihre Internetverbindung.
PAUSE
EXIT
:INTERNAL_ERROR
SET /P %DIAGNOSTIC% Es ist ein interner Fehler aufgetreten. Soll eine automatische Überprüfung durchgeführt werden? (j/n) 
IF /I "%DIAGNOSTIC%" NEQ "j" GOTO ABORT
ECHO Das Programm versucht nun, die Anwendung XAMPP zu öffnen.
PAUSE
XAMPP
SET /P %XAMPP% Wurde XAMPP erfolgreich gestartet? (j/n) 
IF /I "%XAMPP%" NEQ "j" GOTO XAMPP_ERROR
ECHO Teste PHP Client...
CD \xampp\php
PHP \montemanager\apache_config\test.php
SET /P %PHP% Wurde "Funktioniert." ausgegeben? (j/n) 
IF /I "%PHP%" NEQ "j" GOTO XAMPP_ERROR
ECHO Anscheinend ist die heruntergeladene Lizenz ungültig oder wurde falsch heruntergeladen. Bitte kontaktieren Sie den Support: support@montemanager.de
PAUSE
EXIT
:XAMPP_ERROR
ECHO Das Programm wurde nicht richtig installiert. Bitte schließen Sie dieses Fenster und führen Sie die Installation erneut durch.
PAUSE
EXIT
```

PS: If you are wondering why I'm using PHP: In order to modify the config file, I had to use php since apparently, cmd doesn't have any file manipulation commands.

Comment: XAMPP It's self has a file called "xampp-control.ini" in the root installation - is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Additionally, when you tried running "apache_start.bat" - did you make sure this was Running as Administrator?

Comment: @PaulF Yes I did, but it just searched for the real file and didn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @PaulF, I solved it!

`C:\xampp\xampp-control.ini`